# how can I use F11 on my dell mini (with no default F11 key)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a Dell Mini 9 with Ubuntu 10.10 OS and am used to hitting F11 for full screen. How can I get my keyboard to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `~/.Xmodmap` file to use another key as <kbd>F11</kbd>, including some modifier combinations.

The documentation of `~/.Xmodmap` can be a bit cryptic, but I'd suggest [the Gentoo wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Multimedia_Keys) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is an F11 on the keyboard. If you have updated your BIOS to A02 or newer then you can use Function+Z for F11.

A posting on Dell Support references A02, but the current version is A05 so it's a moot point.

BIOS Links:
[Win Version](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R254112&SystemID=INSPIRON910&servicetag=&os=BIOSA&osl=en&deviceid=18840&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=7&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=372333)
[DOS Version](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R215209&SystemID=INSPIRON910&servicetag=&os=BIOSA&osl=en&deviceid=18840&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=305030)

Comment: @A-Rock I see what you mean, but it doesn't seem to work on my machine

Answer (score 0):

This user guide also says you can use Ctrl+Alt+F (page 9)

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins910/en/tb/H840JA01MR.pdf

.

All your Docs for the Mini 9

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins910/en/index.htm